# Read and write different types in vector

Tags: c++, c, arrays, vector

How can I pack in a vector several different primitive data types as well as strings to examine the contents then?
(In Java, this went via `Object [] objects = {1.0, "Hello", - 42, 'b'}`)

The task is as follows:
Given the following array: `[3.0,42, "Monkey", 7.2, b]`

This array is to be passed to a method that outputs the contents of the array on the console. If it is a `string`, each letter of the string should be added as an ASCII value in the same variable, and finally returned as an `int` on the console. With `char` exactly the same.

I know from today as I create a `vector` so with `std::vector<double> numbers = {1.0,2.0};` How to write functions and how to access the indexes `numbers[i];` as well as the length of the vector `numbers.size()`.

How can I solve this problem now? Since I have unfortunately found no simple <- solution for the multiple types in a vector.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a English language site.  Please edit your post into English.

Comment: You could use `std::any`, but bear in mind that C++ doesn't store reflective type information the same way Java does, so recovering that information at runtime is going to be tricky.

Comment: auto translated with google translate.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Take your filthy love community back to your nudist beaches :-)

Comment: okay one moment I will translate it

Comment: How can I put several types of items into one vector? 

I've learned vectors today, because we have to prepare some excercises for next week.

Comment: The Excercise is following:
You got the array[1.0,42,"Monkey",b]

Give it to a function and let it print every item on the console. If it is a String, take every character of the string into one int as ASCII-values, add them together and give it out on the console. Same with single characters.
How to realize? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ does not do type erasure the same way that Java does. To create a heterogeneous container (which is the technical term for what you're trying to do) you'll need to make extensive use of `std::any` or `std::variant`, which are new classes introduced with C++17.

```
std::vector<std::any> values{1.0, "Hello", -42, 'b'};
for(auto & any : values) {
    int * i;
    if(val = std::any_cast<int>(&any)) std::cout << "int: " << *i << std::endl;
    const char ** s;
    if(s = std::any_cast<const char *>(&any)) std::cout << "string-literal: " << *s << std::endl;
    double * d;
    if(d = std::any_cast<double>(&any)) std::cout << "double: " << *d << std::endl;
    char * c;
    if(c = std::any_cast<char>(&any)) std::cout << "char: " << *c << std::endl;
}
```

Note how messy that code is. Not least of which because many people would desire `"hello"` to be stored as a `std::string` object, but this can't be done unless the user expressly designates it as such:

```
std::vector<std::any> values{1.0, std::string{"Hello"}, -42, 'b'};
```

At any rate, my personal opinion is that the use of `std::variant` would be a much better fit, as you can make it much clearer how the container is meant to be used, and you can avoid the dynamic allocations associated with `std::any`:

```
typedef std::variant<std::string, char, double, int> my_variant;

struct visitor {
    void operator()(std::string const& v) const {
        std::cout << "std::string: " << v<< std::endl;
    }
    void operator()(double const& v) const {
        std::cout << "double: " << v << std::endl;
    }
    void operator()(int const& v) const {
        std::cout << "int: " << v << std::endl;
    }
    void operator()(char const& v) const {
        std::cout << "char: " << v << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<my_variant> values{1.0, "Hello", -42, 'b'};
    for(my_variant & variant : values) {
        std::visit(visitor{}, variant);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

We can even make the variant version a lot simpler with `auto` lambdas if we don't *need* to know the type:

```
typedef std::variant<std::string, char, double, int> my_variant;

int main() {
    std::vector<my_variant> values{1.0, "Hello", -42, 'b'};
    for(my_variant & variant : values) {
        std::visit(
            [](auto const& val) {std::cout << "Some unknown type: " << val << std::endl;}, 
            variant
        );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I haven't run this through my compiler, but this should give a pretty good sense of how to accomplish this kind of task in C++.

If you don't have access to C++17, you can use **boost.any** and **boost.variant**, which I'm reasonably sure are both header-only libraries, and thus easy to import into your project.

Comment: @IIOIOE Please make sure to vote on and accept the answer if it is helpful to you. =)